# Patch 7405 v1.1 Installation error - Already Installed Patch 7405 v1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-7405, version

Installation  error :

[image]

How can i solve this  Patch 7405 v1.1 Installation  error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Hunk #1 succeeded at 508 (offset 1 line)`

The message you see means the file was successfully patched, offset 1 line means Some lines had only spaces but they got trimmed to empty lines, so the patch file applied correctly, but with offset factors warnings display.

2. lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php.  Please compare with your version core file. Any space or changes in your files. if there update file and apply patch.

Thanks

Comment: could you pls explain briefly, what can I do now?

Comment: compare file with your magento core version lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php any different is there.

Comment: i am compared my Uploader.php with fresh Magento. there is no changes in Uploader.php file

Comment: okey you can replace the with magento core file and apply patch again . some carriage return and space are not show in different

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: what is the version you are using.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65628/discussion-between-zus-and-rama-chandraan-m-r).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65628/discussion-between-zus-and-rama-chandraan-m-r

Comment: i will finish lunch and come back wait for 30 min

Comment: okay -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65628/discussion-between-zus-and-rama-chandraan-m-r

Comment: I am trying to install SUPEE 9767 V2,  its getting error, there are a lot of files like "hunk ignored" may i know how can i  solve this error.

Comment: can you create separate question and your file i will check and help you :)

Comment: can you please file here i will help you